# mysql table primary key not executed

Tags: mysql, sql

According to the : [primary key defination](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp) It is unique .

In my database I have :

```
:create database college;
:use college;
:CREATE TABLE student (id INT, name VARCHAR(20), email VARCHAR(20),primary key(id,email));
```

this is how I create table in my database..where primary key is id and email.
that means,the value of id and email must be unique.
now,
I insert the values;

```
mysql> INSERT INTO student (id,name,email) VALUES(1,"Vivek","xuz@abc.com");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
```

then again I put the same entry:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO student (id,name,email) VALUES(1,"Vivek","xuz@abc.com");
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1-xuz@abc.com' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

now I keep the **id** is same and change the **email** value

```
 mysql> INSERT INTO student (id,name,email) VALUES(1,"Vivek","hello@gmail.com");
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
```

it is inserted..why? I set `id,email` as primary key..so why these two columns are not working properly?

I put:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
  s_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(50),
  email varchar(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (s_id,email)
);
```

and

```
alter table student add constraint case unique (s_id,email);
```

now it is also giving the same result

Comment: This is complex key. MySQL and all database take both column to check unique.

Answer (score 1):

primary key(id,email) means a composite primary key. The combination is unique and not necessarily individual columns

Comment: so,how can I maintain this two field as unique key??

Answer (score 0):

You have used a `composite key` here meaning that their combined value will be unique and not standalone. If you want unique values for each, then you must use `UNIQUE constraint check` while creating a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE student (id INT unique, 
email VARCHAR(20),
primary key(id,email));
```

Comment: I have tried your answer..please see my ques,I have edited..But it is not working..